# Review tests appear to be too evident

Tags: discussion, review-audits

While reviewing [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts), I was presented with the following:

[image]

While the above screenshot is taken from the review history, when the review was presented the only difference was that it didn't have the "Accepted" checkmark.

The post was in the `Low Quality Posts` review queue, but it seems to be of reasonable length, contains code, an explanation, even the vote count (that might be fudged, I'm not sure).

It appears that such test reviews are way too evident that those are *test* reviews.  I'm not aware of what mechanism is used to present *test reviews*, but it's apparent that it needs some bit of overhaul.

[The review in question is [https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3196429]](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3196429)

Comment: Good, you are paying attention. **That is the goal**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And yet robo reviewers keep missing these, as they are **not paying attention**.

You *are* paying attention, and spot the reviews. Good on you, mission accomplished!

Comment: But that doesn't imply that the tests should be somewhat obvious?

Comment: We just need to test if the reviewer is paying attention and is not just hitting 'approve' or 'no action needed' every time the button activates. Somewhat obvious is fine here.